# Can the implementation of std::atomic with respect to locks change a program's behavior from correct to incorrect?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Are there C++ programs that are correct and deadlock free when `atomic::is_lock_free` returns true, but are undefined or could contain a deadlock when `atomic::is_lock_free` returns false?

Given that any lock inside an atomic will be acquired and released under the library's control, I can't imagine how to muck things up, but with multithreading and locks there is usually a way :-)

Comment: I don't think the semantics of atomic operations are supposed to change depending on whether `is_lock_free()` returns `true` or `false`. `is_lock_free()` will only tell how the atomicity is realized. So I would go for a "no".

Comment: Agreed; I can't see any passage that defines semantics conditional on the return value of this function (or equivalent conditions).

Comment: Note that "lock-free" is technically an indication of whether a group of cooperating threads are guaranteed to make progress as long as at least one of those threads are scheduled.  So if an algorithm has to be lock-free to be correct, then using a non-lock-free `std::atomic` would cause it to be incorrect.  However, it wouldn't cause it to deadlock.

Comment: @Vaughn Are you sure? That's not the definition I'm familiar with. Lock-free for me just means that any scheduled thread can make progress at any point in time. But that doesn't mean you couldn't have a livelock with it.

Comment: @Voo: From wikipedia,  "A non-blocking algorithm is lock-free if there is guaranteed system-wide progress", and "an algorithm is non-blocking if the suspension of one or more threads will not stop the potential progress of the remaining threads."

Comment: @Vaughn Sorry interpreted your comment as saying you have to make local progress, not sure where I got that notion from on rereading it :)

Comment: "I can't imagine how to muck things up, but with multithreading and locks there is usually a way :-)" Love this. I will quote it from now on :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have deadlock in a program you need to hold more then one lock simultaneously. Accessing or modifying `std::atomic<T>` variable may acquire lock according to the C++11 standard, but it releases the lock as soon as function call finished and it doesn't call any user defined function while holding a lock, so you can't have a situation where two (or more) mutexes are locked simultaneously; hence no deadlock is possible with `std::atomic` internal lockable objects.